# How to animate page navigate transitions in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-runtime, transition, winrt-xaml

In WinRT, when navigating between 2 XAML pages with

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage));
```

how can I fade away the first page and fade in the second page? I remember Windows Phone 7 had an assembly to do it in XAML. How can I do it in WinRT?

Answer (score 3):

This should add a quick fade-in effect to all elements in your page. It might be good enough for your needs.

```
<Page>
    <Page.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <ContentThemeTransition HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Page.Transitions>
....
</Page>
```

But I would suggest you leave the default values for horizontal and vertical offset, it would emulate the standard transitions in WinRT.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ContentThemeTransition to apply a built in transition effect.  See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personality-Animations-3f857919 for an example of how it can be used.  Basically, something like this in your XAML...

```
<Page>
....
<Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
             <TransitionCollection>
                 <ContentThemeTransition/>
             </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
....
```

Comment: I've looked at the collection of transitions possible at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452701.aspx but I don't think it's possible to apply FadeOutThemeTransition on the Page's root element to have the first page's opacity gradually reduce to zero on top of the second page...